# CocoaPods TMCache Error

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to use CocoaPods to install TMCache to my iOS app.  When I compile, I get the error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TMCache", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo7TMCache in TodayViewController.o
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're importing an implementation file instead of a header.